# Wrap the widget content with a div and get the widget title outside?

Tags: widgets, jquery

In this [subject](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/how-to-wrap-the-widget-content-with-a-div-or-get-the-widget-title-outside) you can wrap a widget with the title outside but if you don't want a title, a `<div>` will not be closed, and the template is broken. So I would like to do this in jQuery instead of the widget function. I tried many times but it doesn't work!

[My jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/gNzun/2)

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. As currently written, this is a **jQuery** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geertdd/gNzun/3/

```
var $widget = $('.widget');
$widget.wrapInner('<div class="inner_widget" />');

var $title = $('.widget_title').remove();
$widget.prepend($title);
```