# Adding a div to wrap widget content after the widget title

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I'm trying to add a div to a widget's content in my dynamic sidebar.

Here is the register code;

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => "Sidebar1",
        'id' => 'home-sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
    ));
```

But this code causes like this;

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <div class="title">{WIDGET TITLE}</div>
     {WIDGET CONTENT}
</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to do;

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <div class="title">{WIDGET TITLE}</div>
    <div class="content">
           {WIDGET CONTENT}
    </div> 
</div>
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to Toscho's answer here's what you need for a robust solution:

```
// if no title then add widget content wrapper to before widget
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'check_sidebar_params' );
function check_sidebar_params( $params ) {
    global $wp_registered_widgets;

    $settings_getter = $wp_registered_widgets[ $params[0]['widget_id'] ]['callback'][0];
    $settings = $settings_getter->get_settings();
    $settings = $settings[ $params[1]['number'] ];

    if ( $params[0][ 'after_widget' ] == '</div></div>' && isset( $settings[ 'title' ] ) && empty( $settings[ 'title' ] ) )
        $params[0][ 'before_widget' ] .= '<div class="content">';

    return $params;
}
```

From Toscho's answer:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => "Sidebar1",
    'id' => 'home-sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box">',
    'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div><div class="content">',
));
```

What this does is:

- checks the settings for the registered sidebar for widgets ending in 2 closing `<div>`s
- checks if there's no title
- if not, it modifies the `before_widget` output to show the opening widget content div

You could use this approach to change the sidebar arguments in other ways to based on the widget instance's settings.

Comment: I have a problem with that: some widgets (like WP default ones, for example) set a default title if you leave that blank. So your function adds the div because there isn't a title in the params at that point, but the widget adds it afterwards and the code is messed up. Do you know how to check for the title from "within" the widget? Thanks

Comment: Not without adding a widget by widget check or some horrendously complex code to render the widget silently then parse it for a title... Will have a think

Comment: Maybe hooking to this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget would help? They use it (for other reason) in this article http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/11/inserting-widgets-with-shortcodes/

Comment: `the_widget()` isn't used in the `dynamic_sidebar()` function, it's a means of calling any widget with options you specify in place. It's another place to filter though so my solution doesn't cover that eventuality. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I liked the idea of both @tosco and @sanchothefat answers - however I have struggled with that combination because whilst `empty( $settings[ 'title' ]` might indeed return true the widget itself might output a default title if none is set.  This title is then wrapped in the `before_title` and `after_title` markup and again the page breaks.  That's the case with some of the default widgets anyway.

Easier to just stick to standard widget registration parameters;

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'sidebar1',
    'name' => __( 'Sidebar 1', 'bonestheme' ),
    'description' => __( 'The first (primary) sidebar.', 'bonestheme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div class="block">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="block-title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>',
));
```

and then add a filter action as per Marventus' answer here;

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-html-wrapper-around-widget-content

```
function widget_content_wrap($content) {
    $content = '<div class="block-content">'.$content.'</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'widget_content_wrap');
```

Comment: and that works only for "Text Widgets"

Answer (score 2):

Add the second `div` to the title parameter:

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => "Sidebar1",
        'id' => 'home-sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div><div class="content">',
    ));
```

Comment: That fails if there's no widget title - it can be done though

Comment: Yes it fails when there is no title..

Comment: I've added an answer with some code to fix the titles problem. Should probably be merged with Toscho's really but he has epic rep already :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do to achieve this:

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => "Sidebar1",
        'id' => 'home-sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box"><div class="content">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '</div><div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div><div class="content">',
    ))
```

When there is no title you will get:

```
<div class="sidebar-box"><div class="content">
{CONTENT}
</div></div>
```

When there is a title you will get:

```
<div class="sidebar-box"><div class="content">
</div><div class="title">
{TITLE}
<div class="content">
{CONTENT}
</div></div>
```

To make sure the first empty content-div doesn't show in the latter case you add this to your css:

```
.sidebar-box .content:empty {display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Very smart way and its work.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the previous answers, I think I fixed the problem Cmorales identified with sanchothefat's answer. Define your widget as follows:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar',
    'id' => 'sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-default %2$s" id="%1$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => ''
) );
```

It's important that the `before_title` and `after_title` defaults are removed. After some trial and error I noted that the first filter that showed a default title was `widget_title`. Then use the `widget_title` filter like so:

```
function widget_title( $title ) {
    if ( $title )
        $title = '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">' . $title . '</h3></div>';
    $title .= '<div class="panel-body">';
    return $title;
}
```

Basically, `<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">` is my `before_title` and `</h3></div>` is my `after_title`. Finally, use `dynamic_sidebar_params` to prepend a closing div for our content wrap:

```
function dynamic_sidebar_params( $params ) {
    $params[0]['after_widget'] = '</div>' . $params[0]['after_widget'];
    return $params;
}
```

It isn't pretty, but it works.

Comment: Was initially very excited by this approach, but I ran into a problem with widgets that use esc_html($title) (i.e. BuddyPress). When that's the case, the added HTML is displayed escaped and not rendered on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I just slightly change the code so that don't need to touch **register_sidebar**. Register a sidebar with regular way:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => "Sidebar1",
    'id' => 'home-sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>',
));
```

And below is modified code From Sanchothefat's Solution:

```
/**
 * If no title given then add widget-content wrapper to before_widget
 * If title given then add content wrapper to before_widget
*/
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'check_widget_template');
function check_widget_template($params){
    global $wp_registered_widgets;

    $settings_obj = $wp_registered_widgets[$params[0]['widget_id']]['callback'][0];
    $the_settings = $settings_obj->get_settings();
    $the_settings = $the_settings[$params[1]['number']];

    if (isset($params[0]['id']) && $params[0]['id'] == 'home-sidebar-1') {
        if (!isset($the_settings['title']) && empty($the_settings['title'])) {
            $params[0]['before_widget'] .= '<div class="widget-inner">';
            $params[0]['after_widget']  .= '</div>';
        } else {
            $params[0]['after_widget']  .= '</div>';
            $params[0]['after_title']   .= '<div class="widget-inner">';
        }
    }

    return $params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, some core widgets add their own title which then gets wrapped twice with the content div. To remove them, you could simply return an empty string. The only downside is that you have to enter all the titles manually.

```
function remove_default_widget_title( $title, $instance = [], $id = '' ) {
    if ( isset($instance['title']) && trim($instance['title']) == '' ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $title;
};
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'remove_default_widget_title', 10, 3 );
```

Correct me if I'm missing something here, but I think that's quite solid.