# How to check if a widget has no title

Tags: widgets

I wanted so that my widget has the following structure:

```
<div class="widget-area">
  <h4 class="widget-title">Foo Bar</h4>
  <div class="widget-content">Blablablabla blabla</div>
</div>
```

so I registered my sidebar...

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar Widget Area',
    'id'   => 'sidebar-widget-area',
    'description'   => 'Choose Widget(s) to display in this area.',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-area">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h4><div class="widget-content">'
));
```

It looked good at first... but things went awry whenever there's a widget without title. The reason is kinda obvious, without the title, there will be an extra `</div>` in the markup.

Question:

Is there any good method to achieve my desired markup? ( with/without a widget title )

==========================================

NB: I'm sorry if the thread's title is kinda different from the main question.

Comment: [Here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74732/adding-a-div-to-wrap-widget-content-after-the-widget-title) another similar question with some interesting solutions. Did you already check it out?

Comment: First time I read that thread... but the picked answer still have messy markup (an extra closing div) whenever there's an untitled widget...

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no way (thank I can think of) to do this cleanly.

Handling of output and related parameters is up to the each wdiget's individual `widget()` method. There is no generic way to manipulate it.

You could maybe get away with filtering widget save or display instances to *force* it to always have title (like a single space string for example), but this would be meh semantically and likely visually.